# Rounding up a number to 5 or 10 in Java

Tags: java, numbers, rounding

Can anyone help me to figure out how to make a code that rounds up a number to the nearest 5 or 10 in Java.
For example : 
4 becomes 5
1 becomes 5
8 becomes 10
48 becomes 50
43 becomes 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t;
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        t = sc.nextInt();
        int x = t % 5 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        System.out.println(((t/5) + x) * 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also do `(t + 4) / 5 * 5` or `(t + n - 1) / n * n` more generally.

Answer (score 0):

Logic is simple, calculate remainder and increment value based on remainder value.

```
int x=11;
if(x%10>5) {
    x=x+(10-x%10);
}else if(x%10>0) {
    x=x+(5-x%5);
}
System.out.println(x);
```